# Ignore a part of a file with git

Tags: git, maven, ignore

Is it possible for git to ignore a part of a file?

***assume-unchanged***: this can leave a ***complete file unchanged***

```
git update-index --assume-unchanged -- project/pom.xml
```

But **how** can I ***keep one line unchanged***?

In this example: pom.xml

- Line with 14.5.FEATURE-15: This is changed for every feature branch.
- The rest of the file can be changed and needs to be commited.
- Context: Changing this version allows us to link with separate repositories and download the correct version during an maven build for this feature.
- When the feature is finished, then we want to merge this back into development, but we don't want to update the development version of this pom.xml (14.5.0)
- We have difficulty to externalize this version and would like to ignore only this line...

  ```
  <project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">

  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <groupId>be.softwarelab.project.calculator</groupId>
  <artifactId>softwarelab-calculator</artifactId> 
  <packaging>pom</packaging>
  <version>14.5.FEATURE-15</version>
  <name>softwarelab-calculator</name>

  <modules>
      <module>api</module>
      <module>client</module>
      <module>common</module>
      <module>config</module>
      <module>tools</module>
      <module>core</module>
      <module>test</module>
  </modules>

  <properties>
  ...
  ```

Comment: Thx. This question is indeed related, but has no correct answer. I'll inform the author on the problem.

Comment: I also saw that is fairly old so things may have happened since then, so I really think the keyword here is that it is a POSSIBLE duplicate.

Comment: This is indeed a correct analysis. :-)

Comment: Clean and smudge filters have been around for a long time (probably back to 2012), but as you note in your answer there, it's not clear how you would build them to achieve what you want.